# Android Studio GAE: Using Google Cloud Datastore

Tags: java, google-app-engine, android-studio, google-cloud-datastore

I am programming a little app in java in Android Studio and i would like to to store some data in the Google Cloud Datastore(High Replication Datastore) like a highscore or something. How can i do this in Android Studio. I know how to deploy my Project to the Appengine and stuff.
If you also could post some example-code it would be very VERY helpful!
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can read about how to use datastore in GAE (including code examples) in their [official Docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/usingdatastore).